# Poise Archive chef recipie

Tags: chef-infra, cookbook, archiving

I am new to chef recipes and I am given a task to replace the "poise archive" in our cookbook as it is not compatible with the new version of Chef (13). I don't really know where to start. Could anyone suggest how I could go forward with this task in hand, and what would a good replacement for "Poise archive" be which is compatible with Chef 13?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

poise_archive is definitely compatible with Chef 13, please contact me on Slack if you are having issues with it.

Source: I'm the author.

Comment: [2017-07-05T10:24:36-05:00] DEBUG: Re-raising exception: ArgumentError - wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2)
/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/poise-archive/files/halite_gem/poise_archive/resources/poise_archive.rb:82:in `initialize'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/resource_reporter.rb:209:in `new'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/resource_reporter.rb:209:in `resource_completed'
  
This is the error from the log.

Comment: The version of chef we upgraded to is 12.19.36(Not 13). We had to roll back to 12.12.15 because of the error.